# php script to java for TrafficFactory api

Tags: java, api

Hi can anyone help me how to write the below code in java

```
$timestamp = time();

$uri = "https://sample.json";

$password = "*********";
$security_token = sha1($timestamp.$uri.$password);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the following code be what you are looking for?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String uri = "https://sample.json";
        String password = "*********";

        String message = (timestamp + uri + password);
        System.out.println("message: " + message);
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] securityToken = messageDigest.digest(message.getBytes());
            System.out.println("SHA-1 Hex: " + bytesToHex(securityToken));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] in) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : in) {
            builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

It outputs:

> message: 1456907866378https://sample.json*********
>
> SHA-1 Hex: 3a5b2e4857e7ebc9fea31d5a52b5d1fbaef59f53